# view if GL_CULL_FACE is enabled/disabled

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Im using GL_CULL_FACE, an i'm trying to map a key for enable/disable the gl_cull_face. Is there any posibility of viewing if it's enabled or not?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[glIsEnabled](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glIsEnabled.xml)

```
if (glIsEnabled (GL_CULL_FACE))
{
    // culling is enabled
}
```

Alternatively you can track state yourself in your own variable, using something like this:

```
glEnable (GL_CULL_FACE);
glState.CullEnabled = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.
One way is to store it's state in a variable in your program and whether you change the state, you will update that variable.
Or you can call glIsEnabled(GL_CULL_FACE) which return a GLboolean indicating if GL_CULL_FACE is enabled or not.